# iphone sdk how to change customcell colour on selecting the cell?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uitableview

i am using customcell with label. How to change the textcolour of label when the cell selected .By default it is black after selecting that, it needs to be white. How to do that in customcell point. Anyone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In  the custom cell xib .I have connected the label to the customcell.i just changed the text colour and highlighted text colour in the xib .and it is working great.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code(I presume that you have an access to that label, right?):

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    yourLabel.textColor = //Your color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to take one integer. when you select the cell assign the row value to that integer and reload the table view. in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method out the code like

```
if(selectedIndex == indexpath.row){
    textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

selectedIndex is a integer value

try out I am not tested but it may be working